# How to Convert Facebook Graph api request to Axios in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, facebook-graph-api, axios

Trying to convert a Facebook Graph api request to axios format.

```
const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
            '/me',
            {
                accessToken: tokenData.accessToken,
                parameters: {
                    fields: {
                        string: 'id,email,name,picture'
                    }
                }
            },
            responseInfoCallback
        );
```

Tried the following

```
const result = await axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me',
            {
                accessToken: tokenData.accessToken,
                parameters: {
                    fields: {
                        string: 'id,email,name,picture'
                    }
                }
            }
                );
```

Resulted to error

```
 Facebook GraphAPI error: Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because facebook needs request url in format:
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me?fields=id,name&access_token=your_access_token_will_go_here

But axios turns url in format:
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me?fields=id%2Cname&access_token=your_access_token_goes_here

#### Using `axios` right way with `facebook Graph API`

```js
const accessToken = your_access_token;
const { data } = await axios({
   url:
     "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me?fields=id,name&access_token=" + accessToken,
   method: "get",
});
```

Or put in `try catch` block

```js
try {
  const { data } = await axios({
    url:
      "ttps://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me?fields=id,name&access_token=" + accessToken,
    method: "get",
  });
  console.log("response from fb request", data);
} catch (err) {
   console.log(
      "There is an error occured while making request to FB Graph API: " + err
   );
}
```